# Event show.bs.modal fired on .show() for inside-modal elements

Tags: javascript, event-handling, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, formvalidation.io

I just realised that event show.bs.modal is not fired only when the modal itself is shown, but also every time you call .show() method for an element that is within modal.

The event handler is attached following way:

```
$('#modalName').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) { ... });
```

Any ideas on how to make sure that the code within this handler will be fired only on modal show ?

The problem occurs especially if you use formValidator.io within the modal (which calls .show() for  elements once the form field is validated unsuccessfully)

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround - checking on event.relatedTarget what has called .show() and simply stop code from running if it was called unintentionally - e.g.:

```
$('#modalName').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {    
    if (!$(event.relatedTarget).parents(this).length) // checks if event has been executed by running .show() from outside the modal
        return false; // this will terminate and rest of the code will not be executed
    ... // other things you need to do on the event handler
});
```

However this is only workaround - any other suggestions, that would make this solution more elegant highly welcome.